# Simplify Integer powers in inequalities

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

I have a fairly simple expression that I am surprised Mathematica (10.1) won't simplify

```
FullSimplify[d^n > 1,
 Assumptions -> Element[d, Reals] && 0 <= d <= 1 && Element[n, Integers] && n >= 0]
```

I would assume this would evaluate to `False`, but simply evaluates to:

```
d^n>1
```

Is there a function I can add to `TransformationFunctions`, to make this simplify to `False`. It's part of a larger computation, which also yields expressions like

```
-a(1-d^n) > b(1-d)
```

When both `a>0` and `b>0` I would expect this also to evaluate to `False`.

Comment: For the first part, `Reduce[{d^n > 1, 0 <= d <= 1, Element[n, Integers], n >= 0}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Thansks @BobHanlon. Unfortunately that doesn't entirely solve my problem. I am running ```FullSimplify``` over a number of expressions, sometimes the result is as simple as ```d^n>1```, sometimes it's significantly more complicated and does not have a reduction. When this is the case Mathematica takes an extremely long time to complete the computation eventually giving a ```This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce``` error.